# Apigee say no response

Tags: apigee

I have deployed my API in Apigee. The deployment says `The revision is deployed and the traffic flows, but the flow may be impaired https://xyz.apigee.net/collectionabc/v1/getreq`.  Could not understand why the server response is down.

Comment: Suggest you post the question over on the Apigee community forum or contact their support. SO won't be able to help with internal errors such as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Check that there is traffic going through the proxy and that you don't have a conflict with another proxy in the same org.
2. Try undeploying completely, and then downloading the bundle and reimporting it to a new proxy.  Ocaisionally a configuration gets messed up just enough, and just right, that tracking down the RCA isn't practical but redeploying helps.

Comment: I have deleted the existing revision and then uploaded again. Also, when i access APIGEE through java eclipse code I was able to connect. But, when I check with REST service it was showing no response.

Comment: Not just the revision, but the entire proxy -- disable the current one, and then upload it with a new name.

Comment: Solved. I had to change the https to http. Some how my url which was tested has https. Your suggestion was helpful too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted the existing revision and then uploaded again. Also, when i access APIGEE through java eclipse code I was able to connect. But, when I check with REST service it was showing no response.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can have various causes. In my case this happened because Apigee services could not communicate with each other. To fix that, you have to stop all Apigee services and start them one by one in the specified order.